# Android camera intent kills my activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I want to set my profile image using the camera, but my `Activity` is killed sometimes when `startActivityForResult` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

camera run successfully, i can take picture.

but when i press save button after take picture, sometimes my activity is restarted.

How can I solve this problem? Please help me!

Here is my code:

```
i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, 
           Uri.fromFile(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + "/profile.png")));

startActivityForResult(i, which);
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: What does "killed" mean?

Comment: it means onDestroy() is called.

Comment: Do you have anything "special" running in onPause() or onStop() method?

Comment: Sometimes, screen orientation may lead such problems

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Activity getting Destroyed after calling Camera Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014930/android-activity-getting-destroyed-after-calling-camera-intent)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your activity is being destroyed and recreated is likely because of an orientation change; your app is running in portrait, but the camera is in landscape. When returning to your activity, it first returns in landscape, and recreates itself in portrait (or something along those lines).

You should still be getting the response for the `startActivityForResult()`, so simply handle the response in `onActivityResult()`, save the intent in the `onSaveInstanceState()`, and extract it again in `onCreate()` with the activity is recreated.

Comment: See also [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279809/trouble-working-with-the-camera-in-onactivityresult?rq=1).

Answer (score -2):

just call onResume() in onActivityResult. So whenever camera activity completes, your activity will be resumed

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    bitmapImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    onResume();
  }
```

Comment: Do not call Activity lifecycle methods on your own